# Why is Event Viewer is no longer populating the dropdowns for Event Source and Event Logs on Windows 10 1803 clean install

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer, windows-10-v1803

I have recently formatted and installed the latest build of Windows 10 from iso 1803 17134.48. When I go to Event Viewer and either go to Create Custom View or Filter Current Log the dropdown boxes for Event logs and Event sources do not populate, they are empty. This looks like a bug with the latest build.

Does anyone know where this information is populated from?

Comment: Can someone please explain why this was down voted?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?
I'm having same issue on build 17134.112 after latest upgrate.
However, I discovered that the event Source dropdown is populated in Task Scheduler event trigger options, which makes me think the issue must be in the Event Viewer rather than in underlying Windows event logging system.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn’t checked Task Manager, will take a look and confirm I get the same as you. I do have another machine exhibiting this behaviour and I have one that doesn’t so I at least have something to compare. Will post up more if I find the reason. I have raised this through the Microsoft feedback, but i have no idea if anyone has picked this up.

Comment: I just checked, I have the same issue with Task Manager as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't come up with the solution to this, but the answer is it is caused by DPI settings that are above 100%, if you change your DPI to 100% and restart the problem will disappear.

This is not a good solution for me as I have high resolution screen on my laptop which makes everything look tiny. I have raised a feedback ticket through Windows 10 about this. If anyone else is experiencing the same problem please do the same, hopefully this will get fixed quicker.

Reference can be found here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/415943c7-7034-4b57-b732-c025e392b284/why-is-event-viewer-is-no-longer-populating-the-dropdowns-for-event-source-and-event-logs-on-windows?forum=win10itprogeneral#7e316da3-5489-4751-b5a4-c3165daa0900

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/why-is-event-viewer-is-no-longer-populating-the/52ce3a56-13a2-4d81-93ec-4868e9cb1c92